# Columns in Bulma lies horizontally, can we fix the number of column in one row and rest in another?

Tags: html, django, bulma

```
<section class="section">
<div class="container">
    <div class="tile is-ancestor">
        '''{% for service in allServices %}'''
        <div class="tile is-vertical is-parent">
            <div class="tile is-child box">
              <h1 class="title is-centered">{{service.serviceTitle}} </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        '''{% endfor %}'''
    </div>
</div>
```

[[image: So in the image shown, I have list of services which I want it to appear 3 services on one row, 3 more on second and remaining on third and so on.[1]]

- if i keep on adding column it lies horizontally no matter how many columns you have*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the docs, the easiest way to have a fixed number of column in one row is to put them in a `columns` element, and then use a second `columns` element for the rest.
But you can also add the class `is-multiline` to your `columns` container and use [size classes](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/sizes/) (like `is-half`, `is-one-third` etc...) to define elements that fit in one row, so the rest will use another row.
[Here is the documentation about `is-multiline`](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/options/#multiline), but if you want all your `column` elements to have the same size, using 2 `columns` container will be easier.